# using images as buttons in html5

Tags: html, user-interface, canvas

I am making a web app that plays sounds. The interface I would like to use is that of a piano/keyboard. User will press a key and sound is played.

I have used `<button>` to call the functions and embedded images of keys inside them but it does not look good and has a border around each key.

```
<button onclick="freqA4()">
<img src="keyboardpics/key1.jpg" />
</button>
```

Is there a GUI designer for HTML5 that will allow me to use attratcive high res images and assign events to them?

Or should I use canvas to animate a keyboard and assign function calls to certain areas like image mapping?
A large emphasis of this app will be on the appearance.

Any help would be great as I have very little experience in html/html5.

Comment: You need to use CSS to remove the border from the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First include this in your HTML: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Define each button as CSS style

```
.button {
  width: <button width>
  height: <button height>
}
#key1 {
   background: url('/keyboardpics/key1.jpg') no-repeat       
}
#key2 {
   background: url('/keyboardpics/key2.jpg') no-repeat       
}
```

In your HTML

```
<div id="key1" class="button"></div>
<div id="key2" class="button"></div>
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the alt text for an image with this method?  I guess not because there isn't actually an img element any more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal links links (*`<a>` tags*), or you can use input elements of type image `<input type="image" src="keyboardpics/key1.jpg" onclick=freqA4()" />`.

You can of course use CSS to style any of them (*even the button you use*)